# how to parse a json in android java with volley

Tags: java, android, android-volley

How about, it turns out that I have the following json that prints me from a php

{"val1": "1017724", "val2": "545910", "val3": "213820"}

what I need is to access each of them to put it in a textview

I have the following code that brings me the results of the php

String url = "muestra.php";

```
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
            (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    
                    //Toast.makeText(MenuActivity.this,"Response: " + response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // TODO: Handle error

                }
            });
    jsonObjectRequest.setShouldCache(false);
    Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(jsonObjectRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following code it will help you.

```
 @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        String val1 = response.getString("val1");
        String val2 = response.getString("val2");
        String val3 = response.getString("val3");
    }
```